# looping through an html form

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to validate the html form and return an alert if any of the elements are empty on submission. When I test this script, the from is sent to the server regardless whether any of the fields are filled in. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA [ */

        function validateForm()
        {
            for(var i=0; i < document.salesRecords.elements.length; i++)
            {
                if(document.salesRecords.elements[i].value == null || document.salesRecords.elements[i].value == "")
                {
                    alert("Error " + name + " must be given a value");
                    return false;
                }
                else return true;
            }
        }

    /* ]]> */   
    </script>
```

HTML

```
<form action ="some_action.php" name="salesRecords" method="post">
Client = <input type="text" name="client" value="" /> </br>
Date = <input type="text" name="date" value="" /> </br>
Value = <input type="text" name="amount" value="" /> </br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validateForm();"/>
```

Comment: you should also remember that the default action of a return key will submit the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Submit` button's `onclick` attribute, you have to actually use the return value with `return validateForm();`, not just call the method:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validateForm();"/>
```

**UPDATE** (additional logic issue in the javascript)

After looking at your javascript, you have a logic issue that will cause the form to submit even when some fields are "not valid":

```
else return true;
```

This line is inside your `for` loop and will `return true` after the very first form-field validates properly.

The fix is to simply remove the line and add `return true;` after the loop finishes:

```
function validateForm() {
    for(var i=0; i < document.salesRecords.elements.length; i++) {
        if(document.salesRecords.elements[i].value == null || document.salesRecords.elements[i].value == "") {
            alert("Error " + name + " must be given a value");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**Html:**

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validateForm();"/>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function validateForm()
    {
        for(var i=0; i < document.salesRecords.elements.length; i++)
        {
            if(document.salesRecords.elements[i].value == null ||
             document.salesRecords.elements[i].value == "")
            {
                 alert("Error " + document.salesRecords.elements[i].getAttribute("name") + " must be given a value");
                return false;
            }

        }

    }
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ckxSs/18/)

Comment: I think the issue lies somewhere else in the document. I tested my previous version in jsfiddle and it works too after adding 'return' to the onclick attribute in the form

Comment: The above one works perfectly with name of particular field being display on alert box which was not so in the previous case..